# Colour reduction in images not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void reduceColor(Mat&,int=64);

int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Koala.jpg");

    namedWindow("Image");
    imshow("Image",image);

    //reduceColor(image,64);

    waitKey(0);
}

void reduceColor(Mat &image,int division)
{
    int numberOfRows = image.rows;
    int numberOfColumns = image.cols * image.channels();

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++)
    {
        uchar *data = image.ptr<uchar>(i);

        for(int pixel=0;pixel<numberOfColumns;pixel++)
        {
            data[i] = data[i]/division*division + division/2;
        }
    }

    namedWindow("Image2");
    imshow("Image2",image);


}
```

This is Computer Vision. I am trying to read an image and reduce it's color by navigating through all the pixels and channels. But, the colour is not reduced! It simply displays the original image! Pleas help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `i` is never incremented in your nested `for` loop, but you're setting `data[i]`. So in all likelihood, a few pixels in the first column are changing after the function call, but nothing else is.

Comment: The problem is actually using `i` instead of `pixel` in the inner loop.